# Script timeout passed error on MAMP phpmyadmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm trying to upload this sql file that's 225MB to phpmyadmin with MAMP.
However, I keep getting this error

> Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit the same file and import will resume.

I've changed the php.ini file in MAMP like so:

```
max_execution_time = 6000
max_input_time = 6000
memory_limit = 1000M
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
```

I've also changed the setting in \phpmyadmin\libraries\config.default.php, like this:

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

Is there any other solution that works for this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe silly question but did you restart it after config change?

Comment: Yes, I did. It's weird because I see that the limit is updated..It was (Max: 256MiB) but now it says (Max: 750MiB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You need to change the execution time limit in config.default.php as following:

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 3600; // whatever time you want to put as execution time
```

As the script is running out of time so you should have to increase its execution time in MAMP and restart.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I still get the message, no matter what value is in here. Latest version of MAMP Pro and PHP My Admin. What's odd is that I don't have a file named config.default.php but I have a config.inc.php (which has the value), however like I said, changing it makes no difference. I've spent an entire days work trying to import an SQL file with no luck...

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem myself and here is my fix.

I am using Mamp Pro, so I searched for `phpmyadmin` on my mac using Finder search bar.

It found a file called `config.inc.php`. The file was living under `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin`

I then found the line for `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit']` and changed the value to `3600`.

Save the file. Restart Mamp Pro. Database imported successfully.